# Java NIO object to date conversion

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to get last access, and created date of a file in java, so I am using nio, but output is coming in this format:

```
Last access time :: 2015-02-26T15:22:02.988862Z 
Creation time :: 2015-02-26T15:22:02.988862Z 
last modified time :: 2015-02-26T16:06:52.022666Z
```

Is there anyway to convert them to Date or Calender object, so that I can get proper format as output?

Here is my code ,

```
package com.home.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;

public class TestRun {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestRun tr = new TestRun();
        tr.run();

    }
    private void run() {

        File file = new File("D:/Test_Folder/File1.txt");
        Path filPath = file.toPath();


        BasicFileAttributes attrib = null;

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

            attrib = Files.readAttributes(filPath, BasicFileAttributes.class);


            System.out.println("Last access time :: "+attrib.lastAccessTime());
            System.out.println("Creation time :: "+attrib.creationTime());
            System.out.println("last modified time :: "+attrib.lastModifiedTime());


        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error thrown"+e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no, the timestamps are coming in the form of a `FileTime` object.  You are obtaining `String` representations of those objects by adding them to `String`s.

Those objects wrap the same underlying time representation (milliseconds since the epoch) as a `Date` or `Calendar` object, so if you wish, yes, you can obtain one of those.  For example:

```
Calendar atime = Calendar.newInstance();
atime.setTimeInMillis(attrib.lastAccessTime().toMillis());
```

If you'd rather have it in the form of a `Date`, then you can go on to

```
Date atimeAsDate = atime.getTime();
```

Answer (score 3):

Those methods return [`FileTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html) values. `FileTime` has a [`toMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html#toMillis--) method which returns its value in milliseconds as a `long`. You can create a `Date` object from that.

Comment: Its working, I have just tried, I am now getting required format, Thanks a lot